# Given a word, I need to get all variations of spaces for that word

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, logic

Given a word, let's use "Stack", I want to get all variations of that word with spaces.

For example, I would be looking for an array like:

```
[
  'S tack',
  'S t ack',
  'S t a ck',
  'S t a c k',
  'Stac k',
  'Sta c k',
  'St a c k',
   ...
]
```

I don't have any code to show as I am not able to solve this issue. I have a feeling I need to split the word at each letter and use a loop to add a space, then add that word to an array but I'm not sure of the logic behind this. I'm assuming I would need to use modulus `%` but again, I don't really know.

I'm using Ruby for this but given that this is more of a logic question it doesn't really matter which language is used.

Comment: Hint: between every pair of letters, there either is a space, or there isn't. How do you compute every possible combination of a list of booleans?

Comment: Aren't you missing a lot of variations in the output?

Comment: Assuming @Marcin is correct you really need to edit the question to add the misssing values, or at the very least, add `”...,”` to the array. On the other hand, if the array is as you intended you need to explain its underlying pattern. It is disrespectful to not answer an obviously valid question, and you surely will continue to attract downvotes until you do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution.

**Code**

```
def recurse(word)
  return [word] if word.size == 1
  first_char = word[0]
  recurse(word[1..-1]).flat_map { |s| [first_char+s, first_char+' '+s] }
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = recurse 'Stack'
  #=> ["Stack", "S tack", "St ack", "S t ack", "Sta ck", "S ta ck", "St a ck", "S t a ck",
  #    "Stac k", "S tac k", "St ac k", "S t ac k", "Sta c k", "S ta c k", "St a c k", 
  #    "S t a c k"]
```

**Explanation**

The steps performed by this method are shown below. Note that each time `recurse` is called the printed lines are indented by 4 spaces.

```
INDENT = 4
@off = 0

def s
  ' '*@off
end

def indent
  @off += INDENT
end

def undent
  @off -= INDENT
end

def recurse(word)
  puts "#{s}Entering recurse(\"#{word}\")"
  puts "#{s}Returning [\"#{word}\"] as \"#{word}\".size == 1" if word.size == 1
  return [word] if word.size == 1
  puts "#{s}Calling recurse(\"#{word[1..-1]}\")"
  indent
  a1 = recurse(word[1..-1])
  undent
  puts "#{s}recurse(\"#{word[1..-1]}\") returned a1 = #{a1}"
  first_char = word[0]
  puts "#{s}first_char = \"#{first_char}\""
  a2 = a1.flat_map { |s| [first_char+s, first_char+' '+s] }
  puts "#{s}Returning a1.flat_map { |s| first_char+s, first_char + ' ' + s] } = "
  puts "#{s}  #{a2}"   
  a2
end

recurse("dogs")
  #=> ["dogs", "d ogs", "do gs", "d o gs", "dog s", "d og s", "do g s", "d o g s"]
```

prints

```
Entering recurse("dogs")
Calling recurse("ogs")
    Entering recurse("ogs")
    Calling recurse("gs")
        Entering recurse("gs")
        Calling recurse("s")
            Entering recurse("s")
            Returning ["s"] as "s".size == 1
        recurse("s") returned a1 = ["s"]
        first_char = "g"
        Returning a1.flat_map { |s| first_char+s, first_char + ' ' + s] } =
          ["gs", "g s"]
    recurse("gs") returned a1 = ["gs", "g s"]
    first_char = "o"
    Returning a1.flat_map { |s| first_char+s, first_char + ' ' + s] } =
      ["ogs", "o gs", "og s", "o g s"]
recurse("ogs") returned a1 = ["ogs", "o gs", "og s", "o g s"]
first_char = "d"
Returning a1.flat_map { |s| first_char+s, first_char + ' ' + s] } =
  ["dogs", "d ogs", "do gs", "d o gs", "dog s", "d og s", "do g s", "d o g s"]
```

**Variant of @Marcin's answer**

```
word = 'Stack'
word_chars = word.chars
last_idx = word.size-1
(0..2**last_idx-1).map do |n|
  n.bit_length.times.with_object(word_chars.dup) do |i,arr|
    c = arr[last_idx-i]
    arr[last_idx-i] = n[i] == 1 ? (' '+c) : c
  end.join
end
  #=> ["Stack", "Stac k", "Sta ck", "Sta c k", "St ack", "St ac k", "St a ck",
  #    "St a c k", "S tack", "S tac k", "S ta ck", "S ta c k", "S t ack", "S t ac k",
  #    "S t a ck", "S t a c k"]
```

See [Integer#bit_length](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-bit_length) and [Integer#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-5B-5D).

We can map each number `n` in the range `(0..2**last_idx-1)` to one element of the desired array by examining `n`'s bits. Specifically, if the `i`th significant bit is `1` the character `word[word.size-1-i]` will be prepended by a space; if it is `0` that character will not be prepended by a space.

For `word = 'Stack'`, `last_idx = 'Stack'.size-1 #=> 4`, so the range is `0..2**4-1 #=> 0..15`. These numbers correspond to the binary numbers `0, 0b1, 0b10, 0b11, 0b110,...0b1111`. One number in this range is `11`, whose binary representation is given by `11.to_s(2) #=> "1011"` or `0b1011`. Since the third least significant is `0`, `"a"` in `"Stack"` will remain unchanged, but `"t"`, `"c"` and `"k"` will be respectively mapped to `" t"`, `" c"` and `" k"` (since they correspond to `1`'s in `0b1011`), producing the string `["S", " t", "a", " c", " k"].join #=> => "S ta c k"`.

Notice how this this technique is more-or-less equivalent to using the method [Array#combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-combination).

Comment: @iGian, I provided an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
def combine_string_with(s, delimiter = " ")
  combinations = (1..s.size - 1).flat_map { |n| (1..s.size - 1).to_a.combination(n).to_a }
  combinations.map do |arr|
    arr.reverse.each_with_object(s.dup) do |i, string|
      string.insert(i, delimiter)
    end
  end
end

combine_string_with("Stack")
```

produces

```
["S tack",
 "St ack",
 "Sta ck",
 "Stac k",
 "S t ack",
 "S ta ck",
 "S tac k",
 "St a ck",
 "St ac k",
 "Sta c k",
 "S t a ck",
 "S t ac k",
 "S ta c k",
 "St a c k",
 "S t a c k"]
```

`combinations` is an array of all indices to put our delimiter, i.e.

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Calling `reverse` while iterating over the combinations to insert delimiter from the end, so the indices will keep matching while going backwards.

Comment: `combination`'s block could alternatively be written: `letters = s.chars; arr.each { |i| letters[i] = delimiter + letters[i] }; letters.join`.

Comment: `arr's` block could alternatively be written: `letters[i].prepend delimiter`.

Answer (score 2):

Following up the comment by Jörg W Mittag:

```
'Stack'.
  split(//).
  map { |l| [l, "#{l} "] }.
  reduce(&:product).
  map(&:join)
```

Comment: This will return strings with spaces at the end, which is different to other solutions, but could easily be cleaned up afterwards if desired. Also, `split(//)` could be substituted with `each_char`.

Comment: @Marcin,rather than cleaning-up at the end, it more be more efficient to change `"Stack"` to `"Stac"` and `map(&:join)` to  `map { |a| (a << 'k').join }`.

Answer (score 0):

Other option using indexes, one liner:

```
string = 'Stack'

(1..string.size).map.with_object([]) { |n, res| (1..string.size-1).to_a.combination(n).map { |idxs| idxs.reverse.each.with_object(string.dup) { |i, tmp| res << tmp.insert(i, ' ') } } }.uniq

#=> ["S tack", "St ack", "Sta ck", "Stac k", "S t ack", "S ta ck", "S tac k", "St a ck", "St ac k", "Sta c k", "S t a ck", "S t ac k", "S ta c k", "St a c k", "S t a c k"]
```

Comment: A small point: you could use [Array#reverse_each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-reverse_each).